# Word Press Custom Query Pagination Not Working

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have this code for front-page.php , I want pagination of custom post type displaying on front page. I am getting pagination links at the bottom of the page but the links are leading to a blank page with only header and footer instead of full content. What could be wrong?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">
<?php

$contactsHome = new WP_Query(array(
'page' => get_query_var('page', 1),
'posts_per_page'=> 5,
'post_type'=> 'contacts',
 ));?>

<?php while($contactsHome->have_posts()){
 $contactsHome->the_post(); ?>

<h2 class="headline"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?>       
   </a></h2>

 <?php
  } echo paginate_links(array(
               'total' => $contactsHome->max_num_pages
   ));?>

   wp_reset_query();

  </div>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What is your error? change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `true` to see your error and attach them in your question

Comment: Changed to `true` but not displaying any error.

Answer (score 0):

I am using function for pagination.

```
function wp_pagination() {
global $wp_query;
$big = 12345678;
$page_format = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'type'  => 'array'
) );
if( is_array($page_format) ) {
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
    echo '<div class ="number_paging">';
    echo '<span class ="santypage">'.'Showing '. $paged . ' of ' . $wp_query->max_num_pages .'</span>';
    foreach ( $page_format as $page ) {
            echo "<span class = 'number_page'>$page</span>";
    }
   echo '</div>';
}
```

}

Now call this function on your page.

```
<?php wp_pagination(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you using this with front-page?

Comment: @Aurther yes i have used.